# How to extracting consecutive columns from a matrix in R?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I have experience in Matlab. When using matrix in R, I found it really inconvienent.

How to extracting consecutive columns from a matrix in R?

I already know that I can use `tail()` and `head()` to extracting consecutive rows.

For example

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7    0
[2,]    2    5    8    1
[3,]    3    6    9    2
```

use `tail(a,-1)` I can get the last two rows, but what if I want to get the first two columns?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about R-programming, and not specifically about Data Science.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I'm just new to here.

Comment: I just saw someone asking questions about R in Data Science. Then where should I go for R related question?

Comment: Although for something this trivial you'd be better off finding an R tutorial online - this is probably about page 3 of most of them.

Comment: if you're familiar with MATLAB you should consider [this reference](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Hiebeler-matlabR.pdf) in the future.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with MATLAB. Thanks. That pdf helps a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get the first two columns using

```
a[,1:2]
```

or

```
a[,c(1,2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

First column

```
a[, 1]
```

First two columns

```
a[, 1:2]
```

First 10 columns

```
a[, 1:10]
```

And so on.